# "error_UserIsQuarantined" error during adding alternate account to Visual Studio subscription

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I'm trying to add an alternate account to Visual Studio subscription as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/subscriptions/vs-alternate-identity

Whenever I type an email address and click "Add" nothing happens and I have "error_UserIsQuarantined" message in HTTP response:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3G1b.png

Does anybody have similar issue?

Comment: Have you tried with another email instead? I have tried with several email, the issue did not happen.

Comment: i was having the same problem, the only solution was to contact microsoft vss support, provide them all screenshots and details you have. as phone support in my country sucks, it took me 2 days to solve it by emails

Comment: Were you able to ever resolve this issue?